# Why my log file need 3 times the size of physical table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-administration

I have a table with approx `600 million records` with table size of approximate `45 GB`. I just fired a query to add another `bigint` column to it i.e. which should take approx 4GB to store i.e.

```
4GB = 600 Million * 8bytes
```

There is no index on this table. Then why this operation is taking over 150GB space on log file.

This is my garbage data on which I am playing around to learn impact of different operations.

I am looking for reasons for this issue and resolutions.

Comment: How big was the log before you did this.  My guess is you're not running in simple recovery and have never backed up / truncated the logs.  In this case, they will grow pretty much without bounds.

Comment: Yes, I never backed up my db. Before firing this `alter statement` I used `DBCC SHRINKFILE` to shrink to 100 MB as I was out of space. Should I have truncated the log rather than shrink? My database is running under `full recovery model`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a column, each page that contains data from that table has to be altered, and each change has to be logged so that it can be rolled back if needed.

See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29522/why-does-alter-column-to-not-null-cause-massive-log-file-growth

Also https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d7aacf6-ff41-4f59-8d4a-bd0909568626/excessive-log-growth-for-alter-column-and-insert-into and read Lekss' answer.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using [BULK LOGGED recovery mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173529%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for this kind of change... turn it on before the change and then go back to regular logging afterwards. Do the change during a low use time or (preferrably) scheduled down time.

Additionally, if you're in FULL RECOVERY mode (as opposed to SIMPLE RECOVERY mode), the transaction log only cleans up after a transaction log backup. A full backup will **not** allow the transaction log to clean up, and explicitly shrinking or truncating the log in this case will **not** help. You want to set transaction log backups to happen as frequently as your I/O performance will allow for, which may be [a lot more frequently than you think](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/02/back-transaction-logs-every-minute-yes-really/). SIMPLE RECOVERY mode avoids this problem (full backups really will do everything), but you lose the ability to do point-in-time restores.

Comment: OP said the database was never backed up. In this special case the recovery model does not matter, it always behaves like it's in simple model. Otherwise the shrink of the log file wouldn't have been possible. Still, since adding a column runs in a transaction the whole operation is fully logged, so even in simple model you can get a pretty big log file.